# Jquery tooltip absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to fix the positioning of my Jquery tooltip in an absolute way. No matter where my mouse goes or what it hovers, the tooltip needs to appear at the place, as a function of a div. Say, the bottom left corner of a div. It's not so much of a tooltip as a static div. But I am not looking to convert the tooltip to a div.

Is it for example to set the tooltip so that the top left corner of the tooltip is set by a coordinate, which relates to a specific container div?

Here's a good [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kyBwU/) if you need `it`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your tooltip content when preparing html, you can use css.

Here is an example. (Needs some work on styling)

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

/* here are your coordinates */
.box_tooltip_right .tooltip {
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  top: 0;
}

/* here are your coordinates for bottom tooltip */
.box_tooltip_bottom .tooltip {
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.hoverbox:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box_tooltip_bottom">
  
  <div class="hoverbox">
    <div class="tooltip">I am tooltip bottom 1</div>
    Tooltip bottom 1
  </div>

  <div class="hoverbox">
    <div class="tooltip">I am tooltip bottom 2</div>
    Tooltip bottom 2
  </div>

</div>

<div class="box hoverbox box_tooltip_right">
  <div class="tooltip">I am tooltip right</div>
  Tooltip right
</div>
```

Comment: Rauli, thank you very much for your answer. Looking at 'Tooltip Bottom', what if there were multiple hoverable elements in that box but I always wanted the tooltip to appear on a fixed location (I don't even mind setting it to <body>)...

Comment: If these hoverable elements don't have special `position`, the tooltip still appears relative to `.box`

Comment: First box has now two hoverboxes. Tooltips live hidden inside these, but when hovering, as hoveboxes don't have position defined, their positioning falls to box level.

Comment: Rauli, is this using jQuery?

Comment: No, this is purely css, no jQuery or any JavaScript. Very light on browser.